# Starting a augmented reality (AR) app like Panasonic VIERA AR Setup Simulator

Tags: ios4, augmented-reality, uipickerviewcontroller

Im looking to create an iOS app similar to Panasonic VIERA AR Setup Simulator but with other products.

I was trying to figure conceptually how to do this, and where would be a good place to start.

any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Panasonic VIERA AR Setup Simulator
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/panasonic-viera-ar-setup-simulator/id405903358?mt=8

Comment: I would love to see your response for the answers ...

Answer (score 2):

AR apps like the one you pointed to tend to require you to print things out. They tend to use the Qualcomm AR SDK, which is probably the most advanced AR engine around. The only problem is that Qualcomm AR SDK is still in beta testing for iPhone, but they plan on releasing it soon, so keep your ear to the ground.

http://allthingsd.com/20110519/qualcomm-bringing-augmented-reality-software-kit-to-the-iphone/

You could build your own AR engine from scratch, but to be honest, you wouldn't have nearly the sophistication as the Qualcomm SDK.

Comment: Qualcomm's AR SDK https://ar.qualcomm.com/qdevnet/sdk is not there for iPhone yet.

Comment: They announced they'll release it in July, and there have been videos and public demos. There's no information on comparative performance though, it'll be interesting to see how well the natural feature tracking runs on hardware they can't optimize quite so well for.

Answer (score 2):

This particular App can be made with the help of ARToolKit (freely available AR library).
This is how I would approach it:

a) try to play with Freely Available AR libraries (assumption is you have decent understanding of the problem statement , from AR perspective). I am providing some of the (freely available) libraries (from my bookmarks) which I havent thoroughly tested,
http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2011/04/06/corear-framework/
http://sourceforge.net/projects/artoolkit/
https://launchpad.net/artoolkitplus

b) It is marker based AR (Panasonic app, you mentioned). This should be pretty straight forward to register 2D object with any of those libraries. All you need to do is to superimpose the 2D object(TV image) on marker for it to get registered properly.
preparing markers is specific to library you use. I am not sure about the accuracy of these freely available softwares (heard concerns expressed by people, but try it yourself).

c) Any deviations should be analyzed and dealt on case to case basis.

Also there are few commercially Available AR softwares, Layar and Junaio stand out. It should be calling few API's to get the job done using any of these Softwares ( if you really want to have a feel of AR, stay away from these and try on your own).